# Stop and start EC2 instance based on simple external commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance that I would like to have various relevent people stop and start. In a perfect world I would like a really simple way for a select handful of people to stop and start an EC2 instance without giving them too many permissions. If I could make it so they just click 1 button to do it, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Starting/Stopping an Amazon EC2 instance can be done via the:

- AWS Management Console
- [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)
- [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk) for many popular programming languages

The important thing to realize is that **users do not have do issue the stop/start command themselves!** They can use an in-between system that makes the call for them.

For example, if you have internal intranet, you could configure some code to start/stop instances when a user requests it via the website. The website would then issue the command to AWS (via the CLI or SDK), without the users themselves requiring any special access credentials (they just need access to your internal website).

This is similar to your "just click 1 button" idea, with the button being on your intranet.